# How to pass the base class on the caller side and accept derived

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern

I have a service that returns the base class response. For sure it has derived responses.

```
    public class ResponseBase
    {
        public string Response { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedResponse : ResponseBase
    {
        public string AdditionalResponse { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the service code:

```
public class SomeService
{
    public ResponseBase GetResponse() => new DerivedResponse();
}
```

Then I need to handle different responses in different ways. Obviously try to get appropriate behavior via 100500 if\elses is not a good solution. And I decide to have One special response handler for each concrete response.

```
    public interface IHandlerBase<T>
        where T : ResponseBase
    {
        void Handle(T response);
    }

    public class DerivedResponseHandler : IHandlerBase<DerivedResponse>
    {
        public void Handle(DerivedResponse response)
        {

        }
    }
```

Also, we need to encapsulate behavior which will decide what handler to get in order to handle the concrete response and I think not a bad solution for that will be factory. And I got a problem with that because I don't know what to return since I don't know compile-time derived type:

```
    public class HandlerFactory {
        public IHandlerBase<> /*WHAT RETURN HERE*/ CreateHandler(ResponseBase response)
        {
            //decide the derived type of the 'response' and return appropriate handler
        }
    }
```

For sure we can remove generic parameter, accept base class in all handlers, then convert to special in the concrete handlers, but I don't think it is a good solution. So could you please advise how to do that in a clean way, maybe some patterns or solutions?

Comment: I see two options you could give `GetResponse` a generic parameter like `T GetResponse<T>() where T : ResponseBase` or you could give `CreateHandler` a generic parameter like `IHandlerBase<T> CreateHandler<T>(T response)`

Comment: @Ackdari, I can't
1) GetResponse cannot return generic <T>, because it is also determined by method internally, not by caller side
2) CreateHandler also can't be generic, because I don't know the actual derived type at the moment when I call the factory. So the factory should and can determine it internally also

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by creating new NotGeneric `interface`:

```
    public interface IHandlerBase
    {
        void Handle(ResponseBase response);
    }

    public interface IHandlerBase<T> : IHandlerBase
        where T : ResponseBase
    {
        void Handle(T response);
    }

    public class DerivedResponseHandler : IHandlerBase<DerivedResponse>
    {
        public void Handle(DerivedResponse response)
        {

        }

        public void Handle(ResponseBase response)
        {
            var actualParameter = (DerivedResponse) response;
            Handle(actualParameter);
        }
    }
```

In that case, we have 2 methods in the derived handler: one for actual handling, and another for adapting (something like adapter pattern). The question is it okay, and maybe somebody has a better solution.